# get_posts cannot grab from specific category

Tags: get-posts

I'm using get_posts to grab list of posts from custom post_type. I also want list to be limited to specific category. So I tried:

```
$postslist = get_posts('order=ASC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=4&post_type=tribe_events&category_name=Gudauri');
```

This displays nothing, if I remove category_name=Gudauri it lists all posts from custom post type tribe_events.

What am I doing wrong? I also tried category=id but with no luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

In response to OP's answer:

> So you use post_type and add cat at the end. Like `[tribe_events][_cat]=[value]`

This is absolutely incorrect. WordPress does not automatically create custom taxonomies in this manner.

From the OP's comment:

> I'm using tribe Events calendar. Check it there.

Here is [the relevant PHP file](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/the-events-calendar/tags/2.0.9/lib/the-events-calendar.class.php) from the The Events Calendar Plugin. And here are the key lines of code:

```
const TAXONOMY = 'tribe_events_cat';
const POSTTYPE = 'tribe_events';
```

...and...

```
register_taxonomy( self::TAXONOMY, self::POSTTYPE, array( /**snipped*/));
```

As suspected: the Plugin is registering a custom post type, and then registering a *custom taxonomy* to use for that custom post type.

### Original Answer

So, you've registered a custom post type, `'tribe_events'`. Two important points:

1. By default, custom post types have no registered/supported taxonomies, *including the `category` taxonomy*.
2. By default, the `'category'` taxonomy is only registered/supported by the **`'post'`** post-type.

In order to use the `'category'` taxonomy for a custom post type, you need to do one of two things:

1. Add `'category'` to the array of taxonomies supported by the custom post type, via [the `'taxonomies'` parameter of the `register_post_type()` arguments array](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support#Parameters):

   ```
   register_post_type(
       'tribe_events',
       array(
           'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )
       )
   );
   ```
2. Add `'category'` taxonomy support for the custom post type, via [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type):

   ```
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'tribe_events' );
   ```

#### Regarding your proposed "solution"

From your answer:

> So you use post_type and add cat at the end. Like [tribe_events][_cat]=[value]

I know of absolutely nothing in core that would auto-create a `{post-type}_cat` taxonomy, or that would equate a `{post-type}_cat` taxonomy to the `category` taxonomy.

What I *suspect* is happening here is that you've **registered a custom `'tribe_events_cat'` taxonomy**, and then **added that custom taxonomy to your custom post type, via the `'taxonomies'` parameter in `register_post_type()`**.

If this is the case, then:

1. Your question is misleading, because you indicate that you want to use the `'category'` taxonomy in your query
2. I would strongly recommend getting in the habit of referring to a custom taxonomy as a *taxonomy*, rather than as a *category*. "Category" is a taxonomy; not all taxonomies are "category".

Comment: I didn't do anything, I'm using tribe events calendar. So I was guessing how authors of the plugin implemented it. I accidentally discovered how to display posts by going through stackoverflow topics.