# Reuse the "category" slug for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

Is it possible to reuse the "category" slug for a custom post type and still have the categories editable within the CPT menu?

With a CPT of "work" I'd like to be able to have URLS like this
domain.com/work/category

I've tried this code but the taxonomy just doesn't show up in the CPT menu:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Work Projects' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Work Project' ),
        'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Work Project' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Work Project' )
    ),
    'public'                => true,
  'has_archive'         => true,
  'publicly queryable'  => true,
  'menu_icon'                       => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
  'show_in_nav_menus'       => true
);
register_post_type( 'work', $args );

$args = array(  
  'hierarchical' => true,  
  'labels' => array('name' => 'Work Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Work Category'), 
  'query_var' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'type', 
      'with_front' => true 
  )
);  
register_taxonomy( 'category', 'work', $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share a `taxonomy` between multiple post types when you register her, you have to pass an array with the `slug` if all posts types that she will belong to.

Example:

```
register_taxonomy( 'category', array( 'work', 'another_cpt' ), $args );
```

But in your case the `category` taxonomy is already registered, so you have to do the following:

```
function add_category_to_work_cpt(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'work' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_category_to_work_cpt' );
```

See the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) and this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104254/how-to-share-category-taxonomy-with-custom-post-type-the-event-calendar-plugin) for reference.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you!

What if I wanted to rename the default posts category to "posts-cat" so I can keep "category" for the cpt?

Comment: The above answer worked? if yes can you please mark as the correct? it will help people with the same problem, thanks!

Comment: It will be easier if you just register a new taxonomy for the cpt

Comment: Yes that would indeed be ideal however the client just wants to use "category" in the URL. Is it possible? If not then they'll have to have a different slug or share the default categories as per your answer.